# Generating Random Numbers for Rows without Them

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to set a 4-digit password between 1234 and 9999 for those rows that don't already have a password.

My first attempt uses the following code.

```
begin tran

DECLARE @Lower   int
DECLARE @Upper   int
SET @Lower = 1234 -- Lowest password value
SET @Upper = 9999 -- Highest password value

update DestinationComparisons
set Password = ROUND(((@Upper - @Lower - 1) * RAND() + @Lower), 0)
where Password = '' or Password is null

commit tran
go
```

However, this seems to give me the same 4 digits for every row that is updated. Obviously, I'd like a different password for each row.

Can someone help me see what I'm missing?

Comment: rand() is evaluated only ONCE per query, e.g. `select rand(), somefield from sometable` will always return the same rand value for each row. You'd have to do something like `select rand(id + time())` or whatever to force a new seed for each row.

Comment: Is there no way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I have a suggestion if you are able to accept letters and numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
begin tran
update DestinationComparisons
set Password = cast(left(cast(ABS(checksum(newid())) as varchar),4) as int)
where Password = '' or Password is null
commit tran
```

Comment: Very interesting. Still checking it out.

Comment: Actually, the second version can product 3-digit passwords.

Comment: Where are the upper and lower bounders?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one possibility:

```
with toupdate as (
      select dc.*,
             (ROW_NUMBER() over (order by newid()) / cast(COUNT(*) over () as float)) as randnum
      from DestinationComparisons dc
     )
update toupdate
    set Password = ROUND(((@Upper - @Lower - 1) * randum + @Lower), 0)
    where Password = '' or Password is null
```

It uses `newid()` to generate a random row number, then divides that by teh count to get a value between 0 and 1.  This can then be used for the password calculation.

Comment: Getting a syntax error. Still looking...

Comment: @usr: What part of "Still looking..." are you confused about?

Comment: This code gets me the error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'" and I'm not sure I see why.

Comment: @JonathanWood . . . What version of SQL Server are you using?  This will work on versions 2005 and greater (and should work on most versions of Sybase).

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I'm using 2008 R2. It might be me. Sorry, I'm not that familiar with *WITH* syntax. I pasted your code right after my `begin tran` line.